# get Unique Month-Year combination from SQlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, datetime

I have `NSDate` stored in my sqlite table in double format - using **timeIntervalSince1970** funciton.

Now I want to retrive unique date combinatios like

```
{ 
    January 2014
    December 2013
    November 2013
    December 2012
    November 2012
    October 2011 
}
```

Data have to be in sorted order. How can I get data in this format?

I have tried with Date function

```
SELECT date(DateInterval, '%m', '%Y') FROM MyTable
```

but got no result.

Hope for good helps :)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this for mysql or sqlite or both?

Comment: Sorry I have added MySql tag by mistake, its only in SQlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT CASE m 
       WHEN '01' THEN 'January' 
       WHEN '02' THEN 'Febuary' 
       WHEN '03' THEN 'March' 
       WHEN '04' THEN 'April' 
       WHEN '05' THEN 'May' 
       WHEN '06' THEN 'June' 
       WHEN '07' THEN 'July' 
       WHEN '08' THEN 'August' 
       WHEN '09' THEN 'September' 
       WHEN '10' THEN 'October' 
       WHEN '11' THEN 'November' 
       WHEN '12' THEN 'December' 
       END || ' ' || y AS dates
   FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         strftime('%m', DateInterval, 'unixepoch') m,
         strftime('%Y', DateInterval, 'unixepoch') y
    FROM MyTable
) q
 ORDER BY y DESC, m DESC
```

Sample output:

```
|         dates |
|---------------|
|  January 2014 |
| December 2013 |
| November 2013 |
|  October 2013 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b24d9/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

It is ***`MySQL`***, then Use `DATE_FORMAT` function to fetch in a specific format for display.

```
SELECT 
  date_format(DateInterval, '%M %Y') as dates
FROM MyTable 
order by 
  date_format( DateInterval, '%Y%m' ) desc;
```

Comment: Hey @Ravinder Thanks for prompt reply, when I applied your idea on my sqlite table it throws error like "date_format( TransactionDateInterval, '%Y%m' ) desc
 [ no such function: date_format ]"

Comment: It is a MySql function.

Comment: ohh I am so sorry dear, I have added MySqlite tag by mistake