# Selecting Unique Months and Years From a SQLITE database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column called (date) in an expenses table that displays a date in the formate "2015-02-15". I want to build a list of the Distinct unique months and years so that the user can pick what month to show. I have tried using the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251953/get-unique-month-year-combination-from-sqlite-database) without any luck.

```
"1" "1" "Food Shopping" "156"   "2015-01-15"
"2" "1" "Water" "200"   "2015-02-15"
"3" "2" "Car Maintenance"   "30"    "2014-12-15"
"4" "4" "Boobs" "200"   "2015-02-15"
```

So Ideally I should get

```
December 2014
January 2015
February 2015
```

Could someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: [SELECT distinct YEAR(startdate) FROM eventhead] will give you distinct years in MS SQL, but I don't have sql.lite to test

Comment: @DovesandChicks This does not work in SQLite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `date` column is already in the correct format, so it is not necessary to use the `unixepoch` modifier.
Just remove it from the [original query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21252351/11654):

```
SELECT CASE m 
       WHEN '01' THEN 'January' 
       WHEN '02' THEN 'Febuary' 
       WHEN '03' THEN 'March' 
       WHEN '04' THEN 'April' 
       WHEN '05' THEN 'May' 
       WHEN '06' THEN 'June' 
       WHEN '07' THEN 'July' 
       WHEN '08' THEN 'August' 
       WHEN '09' THEN 'September' 
       WHEN '10' THEN 'October' 
       WHEN '11' THEN 'November' 
       WHEN '12' THEN 'December' 
       END || ' ' || y AS dates
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         strftime('%m', date) m,
         strftime('%Y', date) y
    FROM expenses
)
ORDER BY y, m
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with ISO standard formats, you can do:

```
select distinct date(date, '%Y-%m')
from expenses;
```

If not, you can use logic to get the month name:

```
select distinct date(date, '%Y') || ' ' ||
       (case when date(date, '%m') = '01' then 'January'
             . . .
             when date(date, '%m') = '12' then 'December'
        end)
```

Oops, I put the year first and then the month.  You can reverse them if you like.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above but it seems to only return Null, even tried changing the column name from date to Record_Date to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: SQLite has no `year()` function, and `date()` does not have a format specifier, and `strftime()` does not return a number.

Comment: @ORStudios . . . Oops, that was wishful thinking.

Comment: @CL. . . . Those comparisons should be to strings.